# Silverlight: Bind StaticResource name to a combobox

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have two datatemplates defined as static resources. Now I have a combobox with each of those names. Is it possible to have your controls utilizing these staticresources as itemtemplates to bind to the name of the selected static resource in the combobox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that looks quite insane but works reasonably well.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboTemplate" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="Blue">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Blue">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Red">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="Hello World" ContentTemplate="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=cboTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Resource dictionary is fundementally an collection of the `KeyValuePair<object, object>`, except Xaml parsing gives use a leg up with populating it using the `x:Key` attribute.  So this ComboBox displays the `Key` property but its `SelectedItem`  will be the `KeyValuePair<object, object>` whose `Value` property is the `DataTemplate` we want.  We can now use element to element binding on a `ContentTemplate` or an `ItemTemplate` property.

If you also need the DataTemplates available as static resources and you want to avoid code duplication you can place them in a separate resource dictionary xaml file.  You can then use:-

```
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplateResources.xaml" />
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

As well as include them in static resources like:-

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplateResources.xaml" />
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <!-- other resources here -->
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking after I think. I have this binding statement for itemtemplate <bing:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FactData}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushpinTemplate}" /> where I want the "PushpinTemplate" to bind to the value of the currently selected item in the combo box.

Comment: @Mortenbpost:  and your ComboBox can't use a resource dictionary as its itemsource  because .... ?